# PHP fopen and fgetcsv - import not working server

Tags: php, mysql, import, fopen, fgetcsv

Following is the extract of PHP code for importing data using CSV file into MySQL and it is working completely fine with the local host(windows xampp) but it is not working with AWS -Linux CentOS 5.9.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{ 
$host="localhost";  
$db_user="root";  
$db_password="";  
$db='tabel_cart'; 
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());

echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$ext=substr($filename,strrpos($filename,"."),(strlen($filename)-strrpos($filename,".")));

if($ext==".csv")
{ 
        $file = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "r");
        $now = date('d-m-Y g:i:s A');
        $count = 0; 

            while (($ImpData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            { 
            $count++; 
                if($count>1){ 
                $sql = "INSERT into off_cart_table1 (imp_date_time, off_shop_cart_num, off_shop_cart_due_month,  off_shop_cart_type, off_shop_cart_title, off_shop_cart_fname, off_shop_cart_lname, off_shop_cart_mobile, off_shop_cart_email, off_shop_cart_address1, off_shop_cart_address2, off_shop_cart_address3, off_shop_cart_city, off_shop_cart_state, off_shop_cart_country, off_shop_cart_pincode) values( '$now','$ImpData[0]', '$ImpData[1]', '$ImpData[2]', '$ImpData[3]', '$ImpData[4]', '$ImpData[5]', '$ImpData[6]', '$ImpData[7]', '$ImpData[8]', '$ImpData[9]', '$ImpData[10]', '$ImpData[11]', '$ImpData[12]', '$ImpData[13]', '$ImpData[14]')";
                mysql_query($sql);
                }
            }

    fclose($file);
    echo ":) Success: File Imported.";
} else {
    echo ":( Invalid Format: Please Upload CSV extension File";
}

}    
?>
```

I observe the ":0 Success: File Imported." message, but no data were imported.

I don't see any difference in terms of table structure and application folder permissions.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: kindly put it here

Comment: No, it acts as if all are okay and gives the success message. But no data where imported.

Comment: You should log the rows so you can see what $ImpData contains. Also output the $count at the end.

Comment: Are you trying with a big file? Upload size is also a potential issue that is different on your remote. Try with a small confirmed file on both local and remote.

Comment: I was trying to upload a small file - that contains only 4 rows, the same file was used for both local and server. local it works perfectly and no luck with server...

Comment: Please download the CSV file used for import by accessing the below link.

https://files.fm/u/gjxtn7uv

Comment: Finally, found the mistake - error in database structure - marked all the fields default to NULL; except primary. Thanking everyone for the contribution...